# In TinyMce editor, image plugin, how to let the user open local browse window with out modal

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

My requirement is that when the user clicks on the image toolbar button, we directly let the user browser files on their computer without any modal. And once user selects any image, it should appear in the editor (base 64 blob) without needing to upload.

When the user hits submit, it will be sent to the server like below

"

This is an image <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAJdklEQVR4nO2deVRU1x3Hv8ywD6c3s85/uPv3t/7OZ+Zd5d3..."

I can't find any config to achieve the same in the docs. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

I tried finding a configuration in the documentation.
Also browsed several related questions on StackOverflow.

I was hoping to find some setting that would help me achieve the described behaviour.